# How to convert String[] to String and vice versa in Android

Tags: java, android, arrays, string

I want to convert a `String` Array to `String` so that later on while retrieving I can parse `String` to `String[]` with the help of (`,`) separator.

```
String [] ------------> String
//and later
String ---------------> String[]
```

Can someone guide on how to do this?

```
for (int i = 0; i <= count; i++) {

Log.d(TAG, "arrayData == " +arrayData[i]);

    // Joining:
    String joined = String.join(",", arrayData);
    //This will give error "The method join(String, String[]) is undefined for the type String"
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use <s>[`String.join`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#join-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence:A-)</s> [`StringBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) and [`String.split`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-):

```
// Joining:
String joined = String.join(",", stringArr);
StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();
for (String each : stringArr)
  buffer.append(",").append(each);
String joined = buffer.deleteCharAt(0).toString();

// Splitting:
String[] splitted = joined.split(",");
```